# Why does this expression evaluate to $e$?

Tags: real-analysis

we encountered the following expression in a game theory related problem. It is essentially about the ratio between the revenue that one could get by selling items using posted price, vs the optimal revenue (i.e., using complicated auctions).

Define $$V(p)=p \ln \left( \frac{p^2}{p^2-1} \right) \text{ and } Q(p)=\int_p^\infty -\frac{V'(v)} v  \,dv.$$ Then the above ratio is upper bounded by $1+V(Q^{-1}(1))$.

We numerically found that $1+V(Q^{-1}(1))=e$, but couldn't prove this. Any ideas?

Comment: Excuse me, what exactly is "the above ratio"?

Comment: Is it $Q^{-1}$ the inverse function of $Q(p)$ ?  or is it the inverse of the value $Q(1)$ ?

Comment: @GuiseppeNegro the question does mention "the ratio between the revenue that one could get by selling items using posted price, vs the optimal revenue"

Comment: @GuiseppeNegro Yes, the above ratio is the ratio between the revenue of posted price, vs the optimal revenue.

Comment: @EmilioNovati Sorry for the confusion. Q^{-1} is the inverse function of Q(p)